# Rails with_options :if => custom_method(parameterOne, parameterTwo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if it's possible to pass in a parameter to methods when you're using the :if option with the 'with_options' method.

For example, can I call something like this?

```
 
 with_options :if => :is_user_this_level?(threshold_level) do |some_object|
    some_object.validates_with ObjectValidator
 end
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass in the variable 'threshold_level' to the :if option method.  Basically I want to do this because I don't want to have methods like :is_user_level_two?, :is_user_level_three? and so on and so forth.

Also if there's a RAILS way of doing this and I'm barking up the wrong tree please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual `:if` option for ActiveRecord callbacks can take a lambda as its argument so maybe this will work:

```
with_options :if => ->(o) { o.is_user_this_level? threshold_level } do |some_object|
    some_object.validates_with ObjectValidator
end
```

Comment: awesome!  worked like a charm!  I'm haven't seen the "->" character before.  Guess I need to read up some more.  Thanks!

Comment: @schmudu: `->(o) { ... }` is another way of writing `lambda { |o| ... }`.

Comment: thanks mu...i was looking it up on the web and didn't find the answer till your response.  appreciate it!

Comment: @schmudu: No worries, kinda' hard to search for `->`.